# Show: $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with certain involution is not a $C^*$-algebra, since it does not hold the $C^*$ property

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with the convolution and the involution $f^*(z) = \overline{f(z)}$ is not a $C^*$-algebra, so it does not have the $C^*$ property, that is
$$
\|f*f^*\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} = \| f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}^2.
$$
Does anyone know a simple counter example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one, for
$$
f(x) = i \Big(\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x) - \mathbf{1}_{(-1,0)}(x)\Big)
$$
we get
$$\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}^2 = 4,$$
but
$$
\| f f^*\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} = \frac{8}{3}.
$$